# Selecting an observation with a priority when there are ties in their score

Tags: r

I am working with a dataset that looks like this...

```
structure(
  list(
    Condition = c(
      "1",
      "1",
      "1",
      "1",
      "1",
      "1",
      "1",
      "1",
      "1",
      "1",
      "2",
      "2",
      "2",
      "2",
      "2",
      "2",
      "2",
      "2",
      "2",
      "2",
      "3",
      "3",
      "3",
      "3",
      "3",
      "3",
      "3",
      "3",
      "3",
      "3"
    ),
    Primary = c(
      "love",
      "love",
      "love",
      "love",
      "love",
      "place",
      "place",
      "place",
      "place",
      "place",
      "park",
      "park",
      "park",
      "park",
      "park",
      "hill",
      "hill",
      "hill",
      "hill",
      "hill",
      "pool",
      "pool",
      "pool",
      "pool",
      "pool",
      "bike",
      "bike",
      "bike",
      "bike",
      "bike"
    ),
    Secondary = c(
      "trail",
      "surprise",
      "elegant",
      "instinct",
      "person",
      "car",
      "amid",
      "sentiment",
      "family",
      "sensation",
      "affect",
      "effective",
      "ground",
      "hug",
      "punch",
      "maze",
      "amicable",
      "fierce",
      "measure",
      "thankful",
      "like",
      "smile",
      "wish",
      "ask",
      "humble",
      "stress",
      "happiness",
      "flat",
      "bed",
      "sky"
    ),
    Score = c(
      0.09,
      0.07,
      0.06,
      0.04,
      0.04,
      0.30,
      0.12,
      0.03,
      0.03,
      0.03,
      0.20,
      0.11,
      0.05,
      0.05,
      0.05,
      0.18,
      0.07,
      0.07,
      0.05,
      0.05,
      0.25,
      0.04,
      0.04,
      0.04,
      0.04,
      0.25,
      0.14,
      0.11,
      0.07,
      0.06
    ),
    Condition2 = c(
      "CM",
      "CM",
      "CL",
      "CL",
      "CL",
      "CM",
      "CM",
      "CM",
      "CL",
      "CM",
      "CM",
      "CM",
      "CM",
      "CL",
      "CM",
      NA,
      "CL",
      "CM",
      "CL",
      "CM",
      NA,
      "CM",
      "CM",
      "CL",
      "CL",
      "CM",
      "CM",
      "CM",
      "CL",
      "CL"
    ),
    place = c(
      1L,
      2L,
      3L,
      4L,
      5L,
      1L,
      2L,
      3L,
      4L,
      5L,
      1L,
      2L,
      3L,
      4L,
      5L,
      1L,
      2L,
      3L,
      4L,
      5L,
      1L,
      2L,
      3L,
      4L,
      5L,
      1L,
      2L,
      3L,
      4L,
      5L
    )
  ),
  row.names = c(NA,
                -30L),
  class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")
)
```

I am supposed to filter for the first three (3) places (column place 1-5). They are ordered according to their score (in a desc manner in column score). The problem is that sometimes we can encounter multiple ties in the third position. For example, for the primary "place" we have a result like this...

```
1         place   car        0.3  CM      1  
1         place   amid       0.12 CM      2
1         place   sentiment  0.03 CM      3
1         place   family     0.03 CL      4
1         place   sensation  0.03 CM      5
```

In this case, we have multiple ties in the score column within the third position. In cases like this one, I need to look up the Condition2 column and select the one that has a CL. So, the output, when selecting for the first three, for this chunk is supposed to be like this...

```
1         place   car        0.3  CM      1  
1         place   amid       0.12 CM      2
1         place   family     0.03 CL      4
```

We can also see a similar, but more complex, problem with the primary "pool". In this case, we have a chunk that looks like this...

```
3         pool    like       0.25 NA             1
3         pool    smile      0.04 CM             2
3         pool    wish       0.04 CM             3
3         pool    ask        0.04 CL             4
3         pool    humble     0.04 CL             5
```

In this case, we have a tie in the score of places 2, 3, 4, and 5. However, as I said before when there's a tie, I need to prioritize the CL output that it is within the Condition2 column. So, the expected result, when filtering for the first 3, should be...

```
3         pool    like       0.25 NA             1
3         pool    ask        0.04 CL             4
3         pool    humble     0.04 CL             5
```

This means that sometimes we can have a tie between different places (column place) such as a tie between places 3 and 4, between 2,3,4,5, between, 3,4,5, etc.

Any help with this would be great. Thanks.

*EDIT

If all the ties are CL, then we just respect the original order

Comment: In a case like this, it would be good to have an additional criterion. But you have to define this yourself. For example, use an additional column to decide ties. Or order the words for priority. Or just drop the requirement that there may only be three values in the first three. If the third place is taken by multiple values, take all. All of that might be implemented in a simple R syntax. But you have to define it.

Comment: What happens if your ties are all `CL`?

Comment: If all the ties are CL, then we just respect the original order

Comment: @MartinWettstein I can work with "If the third place is taken by multiple values, take all." But still don't know how I am suppose to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's ok to keep more than three if the third (or second) place are held by multiple cases, you can use this function:

```
select_best = function(df,col,n=3){
  t = table(df[[col]]) ## Create a frequency table
  vals = 1 ## Start with the 1 last value
  while(sum(t[length(t)+1-(1:vals)])<n){vals=vals+1} ## Increase the number of values until n is included
  scores = names(t[length(t)+1-(1:vals)]) ## Determine the n highest scores
  return(df[as.character(df[[col]])%in%scores,])  ## Return a subset of the df, that only contains the n highest scores
}
```

It returns the following subsets if you select for the best three values of the different categories:

```
> select_best(df,"Score",3)
# A tibble: 3 x 6
  Condition Primary Secondary Score Condition2 place
  <chr>     <chr>   <chr>     <dbl> <chr>      <int>
1 1         place   car        0.3  CM             1
2 3         pool    like       0.25 NA             1
3 3         bike    stress     0.25 CM             1

> select_best(df[df$Primary=="place",],"Score",3)
# A tibble: 5 x 6
  Condition Primary Secondary Score Condition2 place
  <chr>     <chr>   <chr>     <dbl> <chr>      <int>
1 1         place   car        0.3  CM             1
2 1         place   amid       0.12 CM             2
3 1         place   sentiment  0.03 CM             3
4 1         place   family     0.03 CL             4
5 1         place   sensation  0.03 CM             5

> select_best(df[df$Primary=="pool",],"Score",3)
# A tibble: 5 x 6
  Condition Primary Secondary Score Condition2 place
  <chr>     <chr>   <chr>     <dbl> <chr>      <int>
1 3         pool    like       0.25 NA             1
2 3         pool    smile      0.04 CM             2
3 3         pool    wish       0.04 CM             3
4 3         pool    ask        0.04 CL             4
5 3         pool    humble     0.04 CL             5
```